# $C^*$-algebras with non-trivial center

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

The center $Z(A)$ of an algebra $A$ is the set of all those elements that commute with all other elements. If $A$ is the algebra of compact operators on a Hilbert space $H$, then $A^{**}$ is the algebra of all operators on $H$, and $Z(A^{**})$ is trivial: the multiples of the identity operator. 
I would like to know examples of $C^*$-algebras $A$ such that $Z(A^{**})$ is non-trivial.

The case $A$ commutative, say $A=C_0(L)$ with $L$ locally compact, is one example. And taking products we get additional examples. Are there other examples?

Comment: Group C*-algebras of [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Center_of_a_group_algebra) or [infinite](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1952170) groups give many examples.

Comment: I think that $Z(A^{\ast\ast})$ is nontrivial iff the $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$ is not simple, i.e. admits a non-trivial closed ideal.

Comment: In which conditions is $C_0(L)$ an ideal in $C_0(L)^{**}$?

Comment: $Z(A^{**})$ will be non-trivial in almost every situation.  Whenever $A$ has two non-unitarily equivalent irreducible representations, $Z(A^{**})$ will be non-trivial.    The relevant facts can be found in any C*-algebra book that discusses representations, for example Brown and Ozawa Section 1.4.

Comment: one of you could write an answer